# Standard ASP.NET logger LogError to stderr

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, logging

Is it possible to configure the ASP.NET Core default logger to log error level logs to `stderr`?

This is my configuration:

```
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(options =>
{
    options.IncludeScopes = false;
    options.TimestampFormat = "HH:mm:ss ";
    options.JsonWriterOptions = new JsonWriterOptions
    {
        Indented = true
    };
});
```

And usage:

```
_logger.LogError("Test error log");
```

[image: e]

Message is nicely formatted, LogLevel is set to Error but it is in std out not err

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ConsoleLoggerOptions.LogToStandardErrorThreshold`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consoleloggeroptions.logtostandarderrorthreshold?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0), by configuring it either by explicitly calling `AddConsole` (which is internally called by `AddJsonConsole`):

```cs
builder.Logging.AddConsole(o => o.LogToStandardErrorThreshold = LogLevel.Error);
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(...);
```

Or by explicit configure call:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(...);
builder.Services.Configure<ConsoleLoggerOptions>(
    o => o.LogToStandardErrorThreshold = LogLevel.Warning);
```

Also it should be manageable from the config:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogToStandardErrorThreshold": "Error",
      "FormatterName": "json",
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "JsonWriterOptions": {
          "Indented": true
        },
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "TimestampFormat": "HH:mm:ss "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can look into [`Serilog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console) which also supports redirecting errors to stderr via [`standardErrorFromLevel`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/blob/1f0919ed791159781c234851d338619c18a505ff/src/Serilog.Sinks.Console/ConsoleLoggerConfigurationExtensions.cs#L48) setting - see for example [this github issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console/issues/100).

Small demo (for console app):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddJsonConsole());
services.Configure<ConsoleLoggerOptions>(
    o => o.LogToStandardErrorThreshold = LogLevel.Error);

StringWriter stdErrCapture = new();
Console.SetError(stdErrCapture);

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var requiredService = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
requiredService.LogError("Test");
sp.Dispose(); // dispose to wait for async write from the log queue

var capturedStdErr = stdErrCapture.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(capturedStdErr);
```